# Deleting Iphone from iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

My phone is backed up daily, so all my pictures...are in my iCloud account. My phones screen completely shattered and part of the body is warped and I am waiting for my replacement phone to get here.

My first question is, how do I erase my device as I cannot use the screen at all and Itunes wont let me access it without the "phones" approval or can I just delete it from iCloud settings?

Second question, if I erase my phone/delete the device from iCloud will all my stuff be erased in my iCloud account as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can erase your iPhone from the [iCloud website](https://iCloud.com) or from any other device that you've setup with *Find My iPhone*.  [Here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701?locale=en_US) are instructions for doing the erase.

When you erase your iPhone, your data in iCloud is safe and won't be erased.  When you get your new iPhone, you can restore the backup to the new device, if you want.

Comment: The Find My iPhone is turned off on my phone so when I log into it, it says there are no devices....

Comment: Can my carriers store transfer everything to the new device and then erase the old?

Comment: I can't answer that for you, each carrier is different.  If you're close to an Apple store, make a Genius reservation after you get the new iPhone.  They're best-suited to do the transfer and erase.